# Can I use the google.appengine.ext.deferred library to serialize tasks onto a task queue between modules?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My Python GAE app uses the `google.appengine.ext.deferred` library to enqueue tasks onto a push queue. I'd like these tasks to be handled by a separate module (named `background`), so I've created the following entry in `dispatch.yaml`:

```
- url: "*/_ah/queue/deferred"
  module: background
```

And in the background module's `background.yaml`:

```
...
module: background

instance_class: B4

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5

builtins:
  - deferred: on
  ...

handlers:
  - url: /_ah/queue/deferred
    script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
    login: admin
```

In the default module's `app.yaml` I haven't set deferred to `on`.

Will this setup work correctly? I occasionally see 0 instances of the background module in the dashboard, even though I'd expect there to be a steady stream of tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: Add `target: <module_name>` to any push queue in `queue.yaml` to send all tasks from the queue to the specified module.